# Passing haml-partial to a controller variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a function sending messages to a user on a site.

Function arguments: user_id, from_user_id, subject, content.
I need to pass a haml template to the content variable that supports the link_to helper.

Can I do something like `content: partial 'my_partial'`?

This can be done?

Because I’m really not comfortable writing long lines in the controller:

```
Msg.create(user_id: 2420, 
           from_user_id: 2421, 
           subject: 'Finish now!', 
           content: "<p style='text-align: center;'>User A can help!.<br><br><br><br><a class='match-btn-green-radius' href='#'>Finish</a></p>")
```

It looks like this:

[image: Looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
Msg.create(user_id: 2420, 
           from_user_id: 2421, 
           subject: 'Finish now!', 
           content: render_to_string(partial: 'foo/bar', locals: { foo: 'bar' }))
```

This will render the partial at `app/foo/_bar.html.haml` with a local variable `foo` set to the value `"bar"`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `haml` directly. (Be very careful about indentation)

```rb
engine = Haml::Engine.new("
%p Haml code!
h1 Title
")

Msg.create(...., content: engine.render)
```

---

*Obviously this is just for very simple html, and I'm perfectly well aware of the fact that mixing html in controllers violates all sorts of rules.*